# undefined method `to_i' with Devise from console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am trying Devise for the first time. I've created a basic login/logout system and was trying  to create some objects from the console and noticed something weird:

```
rails c --sandbox
Loading development environment in sandbox (Rails 4.1.5)
Any modifications you make will be rolled back on exit

Frame number: 0/20
[1] »  u = User.last
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"   ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
(pry) output error: #<NoMethodError: undefined method `to_i' for #<Object:0x007fd988871540>>
[2] »  u
(pry) output error: #<NoMethodError: undefined method `to_i' for #<Object:0x007fd988871540>>
[3] »  u.id
=> 5
```

How come the console throws an error on my object? Same thing happens with User.last, etc.

Here is my schema:

```
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have gem jazzy_hands installed? It was the reason in our case.

Comment: yep, jazz hands I have! So what did you do?

Comment: Well we just removed jazz hand , but friend told me that the issue is directly from awesome_print in jazz_hand. Check both gems issues list, maybe there is sollution if you dont want to remove jazz_hands.

Comment: I would have never thought of awesome_print to cause this issue. I deleted it from my gemfile and its gone.

Answer (score 4):

Easy workarond is to add this to .pryrc

```
module AwesomePrint
  class Formatter

    private

    def awesome_self(object, type)
      if @options[:raw] && object.instance_variables.any?
        awesome_object(object)
      elsif object.respond_to?(:to_hash)
        awesome_hash(object.to_hash)
      else
        colorize(object.inspect.to_s, type)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Saved me a massive headache today, this one needs to be voted higher and submitted as a patch to Awesome Print if it hasn't already been.